# Hierarchical Data structure design

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

I have a hierarchical Data. something like:

[image]

The following are the characteristics:

1. A node can have any number of children
2. The nodes can be marked as special. Once a node is marked special, the whole subtree starting from that node becomes special.

The following are the operations I want to perform:

1. `Tree.get("a.b.d.g")` should give me node `g`
2. `Tree.set("a.b.d.g",value)` which set node `g`'s value
3. at any node I should know who is the root node
4. at any node I should if I'm part of special subtree
5. I should be able to copy/move a subtree in to another tree
6. I can add new nodes or delete new nodes at every level
7. I should be able to serialize this data

I can currently think of "hashmap of hashmaps" kind of data structure. I can always cache answer to operations 3 and 4 at every node. Of course I need to clear that cache when I do copy or move etc...

Are there any other ways of implementation to achieve best performance from above operations with minimal memory footprint.

Comment: While not swing related, implementing TreeNode is always a good start. You can then copy TreeNode and make your own custom interface with the same methods.

Comment: Could be an overkill but what about using [Neo4j](http://www.neo4j.org/)?

Comment: What do you mean by "at any node I should know who is the root node"? Isn't there just one root? And is your tree balanced in any way?

Comment: I have reference to a node and I have many trees. I should know which tree does this node belong to

Answer (score 0):

For basic modeling, you should use a Composite pattern:

```
public class TreeNode {

    private String id;
    private TreeNode parent;
    private List<TreeNode> treeNodes = new ArrayList<>();

    ...
}
```

Each node has a String id, a reference to its parent, and references its children.
You can get the top root by iterating on getParent() until its null (use recursion).

For parsing the path imagine something like:

```
public TreeNode get(final String path) {
    if (!path.isEmpty()) {
        for (TreeNode treeNode : treeNodes) {
            if (path.startsWith(treeNode.getId())) {
                return treeNode.get(path.substring(...));
            }
        }
    }
    return this;
}
```

Now if you are looking for a way to store this kind of data (graph like) and to have performant queries on it, you can consider using a graph database as @sebgymn mentioned: Neo4j is a great database for that in java.

It is about using a Connected Data Model with NOSQL. Nodes store data in properties, relationships are also stored and explicitly named in Neo4j and acts as links between nodes. You can then execute queries on a Node (properties, relationships to others...).

Here is link to a presentation: http://fr.slideshare.net/neo4j/data-modeling-with-neo4j

A great tutorial: http://technoracle.blogspot.fr/2012/04/getting-started-with-neo4j-beginners.html

A test graph database to execute queries: http://www.neo4j.org/learn/cypher

For instance: you can try implementing a multi-level pattern tree in neo4j (as in your case it is important to check the top root: so it seems your model has different levels on the tree).

Comment: This doesn't give optimal time for any of the queries. Without knowing the relative importance of the requirements, there is no way you can propose the proper data structure.

Comment: Something like this we already have. I'm just looking for better performing option

Comment: @anony I didn't understand your question. But if you are looking for performance, you should seriously consider a graph database such as Neo4j which is mentioned by sebgymn as it seems you want graph to be persistent.

Comment: I have these trees in memory. The queries are in memory. I put them in DB only for persistence sake. I still dont know how neo4j helps here because I'm referring to in-memory structures here. BTW, I did not learn anything about neo4j. That i'll do now.